# explanation on duplicate attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this code on the sample xslt and i could not make this part exactly. I want to understand this portion `seq_no[/*/*/seq_no[@num = following::seq_no/@num]]`. Any idea?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seq_no[/*/*/seq_no[@num = following::seq_no/@num]]">
        <seq_no num="[{count(preceding::seq_no)+1}]{.}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </seq_no>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the input

```
<xml>
    <staff>
        <seq_no num="0">0</seq_no>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <seq_no num="1">1</seq_no>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <seq_no num="1">2</seq_no>
        <name>abc</name>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <seq_no num="3">3</seq_no>
        <name>abc</name>
    </staff>
</xml>
```

and this is the output

```
<xml>
   <staff>
      <seq_no num="[1]0">0</seq_no>
      <name>xyz</name>
   </staff>
   <staff>
      <seq_no num="[2]1">1</seq_no>
      <name>xyz</name>
   </staff>
   <staff>
      <seq_no num="[3]2">2</seq_no>
      <name>abc</name>
   </staff>
   <staff>
      <seq_no num="[4]3">3</seq_no>
      <name>abc</name>
   </staff>
</xml>
```

Comment: Just to avoid any misunderstanding...Are you saying you are not getting the output you expect here (If so, saying what you expect would help), or is that it is working, but you are just looking to understand the xpath expression you have highlighted? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C, It is working fine, but I am just looking to understand the xpath expression I have highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to understand the expression `seq_no[/*/*/seq_no[@num = following::seq_no/@num]]`. It helps to break it down into separate parts. Consider the following:

```
/*/*/seq_no
```

Because this expression starts with a `/`, this is an absolute path, and will match any **seq_no** element in the document that is a grand-child of the root element of the XML. You that quantify it with the following xpath expression:

```
[@num = following::seq_no/@num]
```

So, it is looking for a **seq_no** element whose **num** attribute has the same value as another **seq_no** element that follows it in the document. i.e Does it have a duplicated attribute further on in the XML.

But the fact that it is an absolute path here means it is not relative to the **seq_no** you are matching. So, if there does exist a duplicate anywhere in the document, then the expression `[/*/*/seq_no[@num = following::seq_no/@num]` returns true, and so your template with match ALL **seq_no** elements in the document.

Note, this is not very efficient, because you are evaluating the expression for each **seq_no** element in the document, even though it will always have the same value for all elements. It may be better once to evaluate it once as a variable, and then use an **xsl:choose** in your template match to determines whether you need to update the attribute value.

Try this XSLT, for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:variable name="duplicate" select="/*/*/seq_no[@num = following::seq_no/@num]"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="seq_no/@num">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$duplicate">
            <xsl:attribute name="num">
               <xsl:number count="seq_no" level="any"/>
               <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', ., ']')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have changed the template to match the **num** attribute here because that is the only part of the XML you are actually transforming. Also, I am using **xsl:number** to do the counting too.